# Where do I use chartjs's destroy function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

I'm using VueJS.

I have a problem with my chartJS's stacking and jumping between two bar charts when I hover over the chart, it flicks between two different charts.

I've read about the `.destroy()` built in function, but I'm not sure where to call it. Whenever I try to use it, it says my chart is undefined. This is the code I'm using to render my chart:

```
  var ctx = document.getElementById("month-visits-chart").getContext('2d');

  myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: dayMonth,
      backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
      backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Visits per day per for ' + this.monthName,
        data: visits,
        backgroundColor: '#CC0033',
        borderColor: [
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    },
    options: {
      'onClick' : (evt, item) => {
        var day = item[0]['_model'].label
        this.selectedDay = day
        this.renderHourlyBarChart();
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Visits per day per for ' + this.monthName
      },
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero:true
          },
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'Visits'
          }
        }],
        xAxes: [{
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'Day'
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  });
},
```

Where would I use the `.destroy()` function that will make it not be returned undefined?

Comment: Why do you want to call the .destroy() function ? For what purpose ?

Comment: @Yesub I want the data to change in my chart depending on which option I select from a dropdown box (March, April etc). If I view two different charts then hover over the chart, it flicks between the previous one and the current one.

Comment: @Yesub I read that you need to destroy the chart if you're using the same canvas to render a chart

Comment: @Yesub here is an example of what I mean: https://streamable.com/zlqnx

Comment: Then I guess you should call the `.destroy()` on your `myBarChart` variable when you change the selection in the dropdown box.

Comment: this worked! Thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome. I make a proper answer so others people could take benefits of it.

Answer (score 1):

You should call the `.destroy()` on your `myBarChart` variable when you change the selection in the dropdown box.